# Constexpr string_view comparison

Tags: c++, constexpr, string-view

I have [a small program](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char+**argv)+%7B%0A%09const+constexpr+auto+a+%3D+%22z%22%3B%0A%09const+constexpr+std::string_view+test(%22z%22,1)%3B%0A%09const+constexpr+std::string_view+test2(a,1)%3B%0A%09if+constexpr(test+%3D%3D+test2)+%7B%0A%09%09return+5%3B%0A%09%7D%0A++++else%7B%0A%09++++return+2%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:53.99056071826385,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2+',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:22.26856861236029,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'/std:c%2B%2Blatest',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+MSVC+19+2017+RTW+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:23.74087066937585,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) that compiles on `GCC` but not on `MSVC`which compiler isn't following the standard for `constexpr string_view` comparison?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const constexpr auto a = "z";
    const constexpr std::string_view test("z",1);
    const constexpr std::string_view test2(a,1);
    if constexpr(test == test2) {
        return 5;
    }
    else{
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of MSVS are you using?  What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Apparently it will only compile with GCC 7.3 and not with the earlier versions.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with MSVC versioning but from Compiler Explorer it looks like that version doesn't support `if constexpr`. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/11/15/msvc-conformance-improvements-in-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5/) page details C++17 features and says "These features can be enabled by using the /std:c++17 version switch." If I add that switch on Compiler Explorer it tells me it's an unknown option. Have you tried running it locally with the latest MSVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++17 `constexpr if` statements [are supported since MSVC 19.11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp17).

We can see in the error message that Compiler Explorer currently uses version 19.10.25017.

Comment: removing the constexpr from the if statement and making a constexpr bool doesn't fix it however https://godbolt.org/g/JhwL2W

Comment: @Bomaz There appears to be a bug in MSVS's implementation of the string comparison.  You should report it.

Comment: @NathanOliver https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/232218/c-constexpr-string-view.html